# placeholder attribute not working when imbedded in iframe in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, iframe

so I have a custom form which is embedded using an iframe in wordpress. The placeholder attribute does not work in IE when the content is embedded using an iframe. It has to use the iframe due to the captcha.  Here's the live example: http://www.uslegalsupport.com/contact-us-new/

As you can see, the placeholders aren't working in IE. However, when you view the actual page the iframe loads, the placeholders work: http://www.uslegalsupport.com/wp-content/themes/us-legal/ifpage-contact-us.php

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

If you require any further info, please don't hesitate to ask. I'll be watching this thread all day. Thanks again!

Comment: Note that the HTML5 placeholder attribute isn't supported in IE versions below 10

Comment: The placeholder attribute works when it is being loaded outside the iframe. It has something to do with it loading from within the iframe that's making it not work.

Comment: I would suggest to use traditional method like focus or onblur instead of place holders, as it is not supported in older browsers

Comment: You got a JS Error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of null` Fix that

Comment: epascarello, I'm pretty new to js, would you be able to point me in the right direction as to how to fix that error? thanks for your reply!

Comment: this is duplicate of same question you asked yesterday...need to fix your other script errors

Comment: carlietfl, i viewed the console and the only error I see is the one that epascarello found as well. where/what other errors are you seeing?

Comment: couple more get thrown in IE8 too if remember correctly. Once error gets thrown it blocks other scripts running

Comment: charlie, i got rid of the errors but still nothing is working. i got rid of them and then tried what sergio recommended below...it just seems like the iframe is breaking everything that has to do with placeholders

edit: i got rid of the errors that I see in ie11, i'll see if i can get ie8 and see what i can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it turns out it had to do with http vs https oddly enough. IE wanted to view everything securely and the iframe wouldn't load without https. So, I just hardlinked everything to use https and put the javascript below the form and voila!

Answer (score 0):

I Guess its a IE bug. also tried it on IE 11 and doesn't work

You should try a jquery placeholder plugging.
look [this](http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html) and [this](https://gist.github.com/akeemw/5114232).

Comment: Sergio,

Thanks for your reply, unfortunately, none of this is working.